# Loopback 3.4.0: Get current userId and assigned roles in custom validate callback

Tags: loopbackjs

With this code in *common/models/model.js*, I can add a custom validation function to a model:

```
module.exports = function(model) {
  model.validate('property', validatorCallback, { message: 'Message.' });
  function validatorCallback(err) {
    // How to access userId and assigned user roles here?
  }
};
```

But how can I access the current user's userId and roles in the validation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is currently not possible. There is a work in progress issue on Github about this: [WIP: Custom validator promises and options #1229](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/1229)

My solution for now is to to add a *before save* [operation hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html) and validate the value there. In the *before save* hook, the context is available and can be used to access `ctx.options.accessToken.userId`. If the value is invalid, I set it to a specific invalid value (in my case -1). Then I can simply add a validator that excludes -1:

```
validatesExclusionOf('validatedProperty', { in: [-1], message: 'Invalid value.' });
```

The advantage of using a *before save* operation hook is that it runs regardless of how the model is accessed / changed. And by using the in-built `validatesExclusionOf` validator, I get the standard ValidationError response.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `loopback-context` created for this goal. But as my experience it is buggy and useless.

But validator is not a good place for your goal.

[Remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) is the best place for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think in my case a custom validator would be the right place for this, it currently just does not offer access to the context. I posted my solution...